# Android get selected item from first spinner in second one and vice versa

Tags: android, spinner

I have two spinners in my app, and I want to get the selected value from second spinner in the first and vice versa.

This is my code:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adp1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.spinner_item, list);
        adp1.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_spinnerlist);
        sp1.setAdapter(adp1);sp1.setSelected(false);
        sp1.setSelection(0,true);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adp2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.spinner_item, list2);
        adp2.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_spinnerlist);
        sp2.setAdapter(adp2);sp2.setSelected(false);
        sp2.setSelection(0,true);

 sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {

         String item1 = list.get(position);   String item2 = list2.get(position);
 Log.e("first spinner", item1); Log.e("second spinner", item2);
}

 sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {

            String item1 = list.get(position);   String item2 = list2.get(position);
 Log.e("first spinner", item1); Log.e("second spinner", item2);
}
```

The item1 in first spinner works fine as well as item2 in second spinner shows the correct selected value. But the value from another spinner is wrong, because it uses the (position) from the current one.

So how can I show the selected value or position of the other spinner ?

I also tried with `sp2.getSelectedItem()` but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found a solution, as the position is in the scope:

```
String item1 = String.valueOf(position);
String item2 = String.valueOf(sp2.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

and in second spinner:

```
String item1 = String.valueOf(sp1.getSelectedItemPosition()); 
String item2 = String.valueOf(position);
```

If the user changes anything in 1st or 2nd spinner, a realtime list is populated. That's why I wanted to know this.

Answer (score 1):

Am not clear about what you try to achieve..
Anyways,

If you want to catch second spinner item in first one. 
Create two global variables

```
Int a1=0;
Int a2=0;
```

And do change your code like below

```
 sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View 
        arg1, int position, long id) {
     a1=position;
     String item1 = list.get(position);   
      String item2 = list2.get(a2);
     Log.e("first spinner", item1); Log.e("second spinner", item2);
 }

 sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View 
          arg1, int position, long id) {
        a2=position:;
        String item1 = list.get(a1);   
        String item2 = list2.get(position);
        Log.e("first spinner", item1); Log.e("second spinner", 
        item2);
}
```